# Raw query on Strapi cms

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, strapi

Good programmers
I'm trying strapi cms and the truth is that it's great. but had trouble making an sql query. a complex sql query the necessary quality raw mode. Can someone give me a hand.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to access to the ORM functions of your models.

To do that you will have to use `strapi.query('restaurant').model`.

Replace `restaurant` by your model name.